# Use Calamares to install Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, calamares

How to use Calamares to install Ubuntu?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

I uninstalled Ubiquity and installed Calamares:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge ubiquity
sudo apt install calamares
```

When I attempted to run `calamares` from the command line, I got the message:

```
ERROR: Cowardly refusing to continue startup without settings. 
     "/etc/calamares/settings.conf" 
     "/usr/share/calamares/settings.conf" 
ERROR: FATAL: none of the expected configuration file paths exist.
```

I assume that I need some kind of configuration file. Is this available from somewhere (such as the Ubuntu repositories)? What are the steps to use Calamares as the installer, instead of Ubiquity?

Comment: Cala does not have an ubuntu configuration file to install Ubuntu itself.  You either need to use ubiquity or install server edition, then tasksel, then install the Desktop components via tasksel.

Comment: `calamares` was used by Lubuntu in 20.04 alone, thus predefined setup was only done for Lubuntu/LXQt (see https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/focal/daily-live//current/focal-desktop-amd64.manifest for the three calamares packages used)...  In later releases Ubuntu Studio was added... but only Lubuntu did QA for it on *focal*